# K Fold Cross Validation in Python

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, svm, random-forest, scikit-learn

I am trying to compare 2  classifying methods (SVC vs Random Forest) in order to do that I am using the cross_val_score function.

It is posible to use the same folds in both methods? In order to obtain a more accurate comparison

code:
cross_val_score(SVC(gamma='auto'), x, y,cv=10)
cross_val_score(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=40),x, y,cv=10)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

That's certainly what you should do for better model comparison. In `sklearn`, all methods that have `cv` as its input, you can either input a `CVSplitter` object or an iterable containing training and test indices for each fold which can be obtained via `split` method of the KFold object. This way, you'll be using the same folds.